# Why is the $S$-matrix calculated using the free vacuum state and not the full interacting vacuum state?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, scattering, interactions, s-matrix-theory

Let $H = H_0 + H_I$ be a Hamiltonian that is the sum of a free Hamiltonian and an interacting Hamiltonian. Denote the free vacuum state by $| 0 \rangle$ and the full vacuums state by $|\Omega \rangle$. The $S$ matrix is computed as
$$\langle p_1\ldots p_n | S | p_{n+1}\ldots p_N\rangle = \langle 0 | a_{p_1}\ldots a_{p_n} S a^\dagger_{p_{n+1}}\ldots a^\dagger_{p_N} | 0 \rangle.$$
However scattering by definition involves interactions of particles, so why does the above use $|0\rangle$ and not $|\Omega\rangle$?

The motivation for this question came from studying the LSZ formula, which relates the $S$ matrix (using free vacuum states) to the Gell-Mann-Low formula (which is defined using the interacting vacuums state).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We calculate scattering matrix *in order to take interactions into account*. Scattering matrix calculation for scattering problems is like perturbation theory for eigenvalue problems - we attack the complex interacting problem using solvable non-interacting problem as the starting point.

Comment: So in principle it should be $| \Omega \rangle$ but because we don't have much information about that we express it in terms of $|0\rangle$?

Comment: You need to check carefully the derivation - one actually starts with projecting the full interacting particle states onto each other (incoming onto outgoing), and then converts into interaction representation - your scattering matrix in the OP is already the final form.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand now.